# Where to download the defaultss.xsl or the official URL (not res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl)

Tags: c#, vb.net, url, xslt, default

When I am actually interacting with IE through a .aspx file. I can refer to the defautl xslt as `res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl`.

```vb
Dim objDefaultXSL As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
objDefaultXSL.load("res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl")
```

But if I am not using IE which url should i use to to accomplish the same?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i am actually interacting with IE through a .aspx file

I have no idea what you mean with this. ASPX is used server-side to dynamcially create HTML or other pages and serve them with a web server to the client side. The client side can be Internet Explorer, but the ASPX code does not "interact" with the client.

> but if I am not using IE which url should i use to to accomplish the same? Thanks

`res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl` is a location in a resource inside a DLL, in this case `msxml.dll`. This is a Microsoft-specific DLL, used when people in Internet Explorer use XML or XSLT technologies.

When you are not targeting IE, this DLL will not be loaded and so you cannot access that file. But if, for some reason, you want that resource, simply load and save it to disk once and reuse it in your other code. Whether this makes any sense, I doubt it, because that file is specifically meant for IE.

Comment: What I meant with "interact" i meant " response.write. , the fact is that I want to use that default xslt in another objects, and i want to produce the same result after transformation. You actually have answered the question. I need to include the dll. Thanks!

Comment: @user3292410: well, that means that all your code runs server-side and it is irrelevant what kind of browser it is targeting. As you concluded yourself, you need to add a reference to the DLL (I'm surprised it even worked without it).